# Download file through SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

Currently I use a script to put an image on the target server:

`dd if=100mb.bin | ssh backup-server "dd of=/home/backupvps/blaa/100mb.bin"`

However, how can I retrieve this very same file? I'd rather not use any FTP or Web server, but native commands.

Comment: If ssh works, you should be able to use scp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for some reason scp doesn't work for this purpose, you can simply:

```
ssh backup-server 'cat /home/backupvps/blaa/100mb.bin' > 100mb.bin
```

Comment: Thanks, using this right now! I prefer this over scp as I can pipe it through to `lzop`. ;-)

Comment: You can always use `scp -o Compression=yes -o CompressionLevel=9` to get gzip at the transport level.

Comment: @DanielPittman Absolutely.  In this case, though, lzop might have some advantages over the built-in gzip capability for certain types of connections, so something like `ssh backup-server 'cat somefile | lzop' | lzop -d - > somefile` might be very useful.  For bonus points, work `pv` into it somewhere.  Similarly, for very small connections with beefy boxen at either end, I've been known to pipe through `bzip2`/`bzcat`.

Answer (score 5):

As Max Alginin says, `scp` should work fine:

`scp user@backup-server:/home/backupvps/blaa/100mb.bin /some/location/here/`

I'd look into `rsync` though; uses a delta transfer algorithm, more efficient.

Comment: rsync will still be slow for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

A lightweight option is to use [netcat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/). ( [Illustration](http://www.screenage.de/blog/2007/12/30/using-netcat-and-tar-for-network-file-transfer/) )